# Determing winner given results table using SQL query

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
   id|WonTeam|LostTeam
    1| t1    | t2
    2| t2    | t3
    3| t1    | t2
    4| t3    | t2
    5| t1    | t4
    etc....
```

I want to find the team who won hat trick. Eg, here t1 won hat trick. Is is possible to write in single select statment?

Comment: Would you define "hat trick"?

Comment: Please use meaningful titles in future - "what is the solution for this?" isn't very helpful when scanning the front page for questions of interest `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes a couple of assumptions which weren't clear from your question.
I'm taking "hat trick" to mean win 3 games *in a row*.  Since there aren't any timestamps, I'm also assuming that `Id` gives chronological order.  The query is a bit clumsy feeling, and I feel like there ought to be a way to tighten it up, but it works.  Basically, for each record, I count the number of wins since the most recent loss.  If this is >= 3, you have a hat trick.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(R.Win) FROM Results R
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS WinStreak
    FROM Results T
    WHERE T.Win = R.Win AND T.Id <= R.Id
        AND T.Id >= (
            SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Id), T.Id)
            FROM Results S
            WHERE S.Lose = R.Win AND S.Id <= R.Id
        )
) X
WHERE X.WinStreak >= 3
```

In this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9acaf/6), I added more victories for team 2, but since they didn't occur in a row, they don't count as a hat trick.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited data and details this should work:

```
SELECT WonTeam
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY WonTeam
HAVING Count(WonTeam) > 2
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0ad2/1)

Comment: Only problem is I believe a hat trick is defined as winning 3 games in a row.

Comment: @Bort you are probably correct but given the data that was provided this should work.

Comment: I think Bort is right, but without a timestamp, that's not possible to determine (unless `id` is used - which isn't elegant).

Comment: @halfer I agree, there needs to be something to identify that the games are in a row but that wasn't provided. :)